# Unable to load Evernote Apple Script library

Tags: evernote

I'm attempting to automate a few things with Evernote and unable to get the application to load in to the Script Editor library. When I do, I get a message saying the item is not scriptable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzGfz.png)

My Evernote version information says the following:
10.30.6-mac-ddl-public
Editor: v140.0.17554
Service: v1.47.4

I am on macOS version 12.1 with an M1 Pro.

How can I load the Evernote Apple Script library?

Answer (score 0):

The message is correct. Starting with version 10, Evernote does not have AppleScript support.

Comment: See for example https://forums.getdrafts.com/t/evernote-mac-app-drops-applescript-support/8716

Comment: Thank you for the info! I'll see if I can use the legacy client. I was going off this dev doc which doesn't say anything about deprecating the functionality: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/applescript.php.

Comment: Yeah, that discussion tells you how to download an older version of Evernote, so that might be the way to go.